# About: intonation_''wh-question''

Tags: pronunciation, intonation, yes-no, what

This is a simple one.

- Could you tell me what "Carbonara" is?

Now. The question is: Which intonation should be used? 
Is it a yes/no question or a wh-question? 
-It is a polite request for information, so obviously I am not expecting a "yes/no" answer. But it functions as a "what-question", right? I am not sure if maybe the grammar requires me to consider it as a yes/no question.

I am a bit confused. Although, I am having a feeling that the answer is really simple and that I am currently having a blonde-moment. 
Please help me get rid of my doubt!

Comment: Intonation goes with the form. This has the form of a yes/no question (_`Aux - Pronoun - Verb Phrase`_) and therefore there should be an up intonation.

Comment: You would do well do find an alternative expression to "blonde-moment".

Comment: Why? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

> Intonation goes with the form. This has the form of a yes/no question (*Aux - Pronoun - Verb Phrase*) and therefore there should be an up intonation. – John Lawler